# This error occurred when using springsecurity for database user verification: IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected list containing Map, List, Boolean, Integer, Long, Double, String and Date
```

This error occurred when I used springsecurty to query the database for a certain user

What errors may be causing the problem?